# Redirect Directory Index Only

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, directory, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect visitors of `/tools/` to `/tools-reroute`, which is fairly straightforward.

The tricky part is that I do not want pages in sub-directories such as `/tools/tool1` to be redirected.

The reason for all of this is that I am trying to include custom web-apps on the same domain as a WordPress site. Curious users would go back to `/tools/` to see what else lies there, only to find a directory index, which is not ideal. Redirecting to `/tools-reroute` lands them on a WordPress page. If there is a different solution entirely, I'm all ears. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line on top of existing Wordpress rules in the main Wordpress .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^tools/?$ /tools-reroute [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. If you're so inclined - how might I keep the address bar showing only `/tools/` to the user?

Comment: You can just remove `R=301` for that. Thus this rule: `RewriteRule ^tools/?$ /tools-reroute [L,NC]`

Comment: Hm, it throws a 404, but I can live with an ugly URL for now. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, I think it throws 404 because of underlying WP rules.